# JavaFX Runtime Version will not update no matter what I do on Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, sdk

Essentially as the title says, I am trying to update my JavaFX version.

Every time I run my code in IntelliJ I see the following Warning.[image]

I have this library applied to my project module:
[image]

And this is my SDK:

[image]

Also this is my runtime configuration:
[image]

I have tried everything I possibly could, watched every youtube video, every guide. Nothing is working, please help.

E:

This is my Windows environment variables path:

[image]

Comment: Did you check the environment variables in case you still have the old JavaFX version somewhere in PATH?

Comment: @CrazyCoder on IntelliJ or windows itself? Not too sure how all this works together

Comment: Windows, it looks like you have some older JavaFX installation libraries picked up for some reason.

Comment: @CrazyCoder edited my post to show you my environment variables, no older JavaFX in sight

Comment: Does it run from the command line per https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx ?